# Synchronize Gameobjects over network in Unity

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am making an online turn-based card game, but I'm having trouble with syncing up the GameObjects.

I'm using parents to sort the cards between the deck and to deal to each player. The deck and all players are GameObjects that the cards become children of, depending on their position in the game.

The cards are instantiated on the network when the server is initialized. They can be seen on all connected clients, but only the host has the parent information, which is where my problem lies.

```
void Update () {
     if (Network.isServer) {
         // Send RPC to all non-host clients
         networkView.RPC("setParentName", RPCMode.Others, cardParent);
     } else {
         switch (cardParent) {
             case "pHand":
                 card.transform.SetParent(pHand.transform);
                 break;
             case "pBoard":
                 card.transform.SetParent(pBoard.transform);
                 break;
             case "oHand":
                 card.transform.SetParent(oHand.transform);
                 break;
             case "oBoard":
                 card.transform.SetParent(oBoard.transform);
                 break;
             case "tmpDeck":
                 card.transform.SetParent(tmpDeck.transform);
                 break;
             case "deck":
                 card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform);
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }
 }

 [RPC] void setParentName (string parent) {
     cardParent = card.transform.parent.name;
     Debug.Log ("Sent parent info : " + cardParent);
 }
```

Hopefully you can tell from the code that I'm trying to send an RPC containing a String that saves each card parent name, from the host to all other clients. However I don't understand RPCs and I'm clearly not using it right somehow. I should mention that this seems to cause the receiving client to crash a lot.

I've been stumped with this for a while and any help would be greatly appreciated!